# What is the behaviour of Secrets for Kubernetes ServiceAccounts?

Tags: kubernetes

`kubectl explain serviceaccount.secrets` describes ServiceAccount Secrets as the secrets allowed to be used by Pods running using this ServiceAccount, but what effect does adding a Secret name to this list have?

The ServiceAccount token Secret (which is automatically added to this list) gets automatically mounted as a volume into all containers in a Pod running using this ServiceAccount (as long as the ServiceAccount admission controller is enabled), but what happens for other secrets?

Answer (score 1):

It holds the name of all secrets containing tokens for that SA so when the controller goes to rotate things, it knows where to find them.

Comment: I don't think ServiceAccount tokens are rotated automatically (only projected ServiceAccount tokens), but I did mention ServiceAccount tokens in the question and I was specifically wondering about other secrets. For example, you can associate basic auth credentials with a ServiceAccount: https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/docs/auth.md#configuring-basic-auth-authentication-for-git. I'm not sure what effect this has though

Comment: They are currently not rotated, however it is planned for the future.